# Regular Expression for Barcode String

Tags: java, android, regex, string, barcode

I am trying to decode the barcode string into data. How to extract data from barcode string, like GTIN, Amount, Best Before, Net Weight.. etc.? Is there any regular expression for it.?

According to GS 128 Barcodes, Barcode contains values about Amount, Packed Date, Expiry Date, GTIN. So is there any common java class or something to extract data from barcode string.?

Comment: What does your barcode String look like?  If it's an actual barcode, then no, regular expressions will not do that for you.

Comment: I've changed question please take a look

Comment: Would `String.split(" ")` be satisfactory?

Comment: Yes. You can extract the details from barcode string, for more info check out this URL.
https://github.com/tmattsson/gs1utils

Answer (score 1):

Extract data with regex is possible, for that, you must check your barcode AI by AI.

Example:
If your barcode contains

`<GTIN> <Number of units contained> <Expiration Date> <Net Weight in Kg>`

1. Your barcode must start with **`01`** (for GTIN) followed by 14 digits.

   - In regex = `01\d{14}`
2. Then your barcode must have the string **`37`** (Number of units contained) followed by 1 to 8 digits and endded by the non printed character FNC1 (29 in decimal, 1D in hexa)

   - in regex = `37\d{1,8}\x1D`
3. **`17`** must follow (Expiration date) followed by 6 digits (YYMMDD)

   - in regex = 17\d{6}
4. Finally, the code must end with "310y" (Net Weight) followed by 6 digits. 
   "y" in 310y is the position of the decimal separator (min 0, max 5)
   (*If you have 3100123456 then the weight is 123456Kg. If you have 3101123456, the weight is 12345,6Kg... If you have 3105123456, the weight is 1,23456Kg*)

   - in regex = `310[0-5]\d{6}`

So, for this barcode format, your regex was (with group and with escape characters):

```
^(01)(\\d{14})(37)(\\d{1,8})\\x1D(17)(\\d{6})(310[0-5])(\\d{6})$
```

You can check all existing codes (and their regex) here :
https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes/application-identifiers